# Unset session after sometime [How to Delete Data After Some Time]

Tags: php, session-timeout, unset

i have a Simple Chat script of php it has no database it work fine. but it create and store all chats in a file **msg.html** i want to delete these chats after some time. How to delete these chats after some time about 30min.

The Php Code is here below

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['msg'])){
        if (file_exists('msg.html')) {
           $f = fopen('msg.html',"a+");
        } else {
           $f = fopen('msg.html',"w+");
        }
      $nick = isset($_GET['nick']) ? $_GET['nick'] : "Hidden";
      $msg  = isset($_GET['msg']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['msg']) : ".";
      $line = "<p><span class=\"name\">$nick: </span><span class=\"txt\">$msg</span></p>";
        fwrite($f,$line."\r\n");
        fclose($f);

        echo $line;

    } else if (isset($_GET['all'])) {
       $flag = file('msg.html');
       $content = "";
       foreach ($flag as $value) {
        $content .= $value;
       }
       echo $content;

    }
?>
```

Please Help me...

Comment: Probably you will need to use Cron Jobs

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use a [`cron`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5/). You can execute a cleanup PHP script every X minutes, like so:

`0,30 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/cleanup_script.php`

If you want to empty the file, that's easy - you can just use `file_put_contents($file, '');`

If you want to delete specific messages you'll need to add a timestamp to the start of each line (You can remove it when you output the chat) and parse it in your cleanup script.

**Note**

You can obtain the path to php by running `which php` on your command line.

Comment: I gave you the code for the cron, (30 is minutes by the way.. I also linked the documentation), to edit your list of cron jobs type `crontab -e` in your terminal. This is assuming you're running a *nix based OS - if you're on Windows (god forbid), you can use `scheduled events`.

Comment: dear sir i am not a php programer please explain in the uper code wher i add your code and which name *.php file i make and what i put in this file and the output of the chat in *.html file and this script contain only three files (index.php,msg.html and message.php) all in one root directory eg: example.com/chat/

Comment: If you put the `0,30 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/cleanup_script.php` line into your `crontab -e` (Be sure to update your paths, I can't give you them as every server is different). Then in your `cleanup_script.php` you will need to put the PHP for emptying the .html file using one of the two options I mentioned above.